# Navigating a list with keystrokes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a list of items that I want the user to be able to interact with using the keyboard.  So something like this...

```
<ul contenteditable="true">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

My understanding is in order to capture keydown/keyup events, I have to set the contenteditable attribute.  This works, but now the contents of the li's are editable which I don't want.  I simply need to capture keydown/keyup events.

How can I capture these events without making the content editable?

**EDIT**

Thanks to jumpingcode, the following works to keep it read-only...

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

... but I am still left with a blinking cursor on the li.  How do I get rid of that?

**EDIT**

Started bounty, need the following updates to the preventDefault answer below.

1. How to get rid of blinking cursor?
2. How to make non-selectable?  I really only want to capture keydown events!  If I can accomplish that without setting contenteditable that would be preferable.
3. I can capture keydown at the document level, but then the question becomes where did the keydown eminate from?  There could be several plugins in play, all needing to respond to the same event, but only when they are the active scope.

Comment: Wow, what happens ? Tell us why not

Comment: Try reading about 'tabindex' it might come handy to navigate through a page.

Comment: @MilchePatern Could you convert your first comment into a sentence?

Comment: @jumpingcode I strongly recommend to NOT use the name 'event' for a function(parameter-name)  like in function (event). It is an Internet Explorer global variable name, so might lead to something verry buggy. But this is no more relevant hence OP was modified.

Comment: Using `contenteditable` only to navigate through list items with the keyboard arrows is a big botched job. You do not need to edit the content as you said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, you do not need to edit the list items, so there is no reason to use `contenteditable`.

What you need is an index that corresponds to the current active item of the list and functions for increment and decrement that index when an arrow is pressed. Here is a constructor function that implements the functionality you need:

```
var NavigableList = function (ul, selectedClass, activeClass) {
    var list   = null,
        index  = 0,
        walk   = function (step) {
            var walked = true;
            index += step;
            if (index < 0 || index === list.length) {
                index -= step;
                walked = false;
            }
            return walked;
        },
        active = false;
    this.active = function (state) {
        if (state !== active) {
            active = state;
            if (active) {
                ul.addClass(activeClass);
            } else {
                ul.removeClass(activeClass);
            }
        }
    };
    this.isActive = function () {
        return active;
    };
    this.down = function () {
        var previous = index,
            changed  = false;
        if (walk(1)) {
            $(list[previous]).removeClass(selectedClass);
            $(list[index]).addClass(selectedClass);
            changed = true;
        }
        return changed;
    };
    this.up = function () {
        var previous = index,
            changed  = false;
        if (walk(-1)) {
            $(list[previous]).removeClass(selectedClass);
            $(list[index]).addClass(selectedClass);
            changed = true;
        }
        return changed;
    };
    this.currentIndex = function () {
        return index;
    };
    this.currentElementx = function () {
        return $(list[index]);
    };
    ul = $(ul);
    list = ul.find('>li');
    selectedClass = selectedClass || 'current';
    activeClass = activeClass || 'active';
    $(ul).click(function (e) {
        this.active(true);
        NavigableList.activeList = this;
    }.bind(this));
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var event = $.Event('change');
        if (this.isActive() && e.keyCode === 40) {
            if (this.down()) {
                event.selected = $(list[index]);
                event.index = index;
                ul.trigger(event);
            }
        } else if (this.isActive() && e.keyCode === 38) {
            if (this.up()) {
                event.selected = $(list[index]);
                event.index = index;
                ul.trigger(event);
            }
        }
    }.bind(this));
    $(list[index]).addClass(selectedClass);
};
```

Using this is quite easy:

```
var list = new NavigableList($('#list'), 'current', 'active'),
    list2 = new NavigableList($('#list2'));
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (NavigableList.activeList) {
        switch (NavigableList.activeList) {
            case list:
                list2.active(false);
                break;
            case list2:
                list.active(false);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        list.active(false);
        list2.active(false);
    }
    NavigableList.activeList = null;
});
```

Also, I implemented a `change` event on the list that you can use this way:

```
$('#list').change(function (e) {
    console.log('List. Selected: ' + e.index);
});
$('#list2').change(function (e) {
    console.log('List 2. Selected: ' + e.index);
});
```

For cross-browser compatibility you'll need this before all Javascript code:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }
    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };
    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();
    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8pqK/4/).

Comment: Thanks @jackflash.  Much appreciated.  One question remains, and that is #3 above.  There could be several lists on the page interested in a keydown event when that list is 'active'.  If you have, say, 3 ul lists on the page, then how does each one know if the keydown event is for itself and not for another on the same page?

Comment: @John Now you can handle multiple lists. Just click on each one to set the focus on it and then you can navigate it using the keyboard arrows. Check out the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul contenteditable="true">
   <li tabindex="1">Item 1</li>
   <li tabindex="2">Item 2</li>
   <li tabindex="3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Tabindex will set the tab order of elements in your HTML.

Comment: Not sure how that helps?  At this point I don't need tab functionality, but just up/down arrow keys.  I have that working with contenteditable, but I just need to get rid of the caret.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I read the question as just with the keyboard in general, not with the arrow keys.